# What is the cookie path if I am using XAMPP?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to find the cookie that I created using Google Chrome and on the XAMPP server. I am using the Cookies.js plugin. I know the cookie is being created successfully because my website loads up the settings that I write into the cookie, but I can't find it in `htdocs` which I believe is the root folder. The cookie path is the default (root) path.

Answer (score 2):

So after a bit of poking around, I finally found the cookie.

In Chrome, it's stored in either of the two paths below:

> 1. C:\Users\your username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
> 2. C:\Users\your username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage

answer is here: https://superuser.com/questions/459426/where-does-chrome-store-its-cookie-file

or it can be accessed by typing the following in the URL bar

> chrome://settings/cookies

In Firefox, it can be accessed at

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\random characters

answer is also here: https://superuser.com/questions/387372/where-does-firefox-keep-cookies

I checked the paths myself so I am pretty sure that they are right. Correct me if I am wrong. I also noticed that the paths change between some versions of the same browser so beware of that too.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are not created in /htdocs folder, they are being held only in browser. For more information check

http://www.allaboutcookies.org/

Comment: Thanks. Some answers made it seem like it was being stored in the root path. I will give the allaboutcookies a read and see how to go about.